# relationship between SAT and Min-ones SAT

Tags: complexity-theory, satisfiability

If SAT can be decided in polynomial time, is it clear that Min-ones SAT can be decided in polynomial time? The idea I had was to take a poly decider of SAT and try it on a formula OR'd with all settings of the variables with exactly $k$ ones. If it is satisfiable for $k = 1$, then we know the Min-ones SAT on the formula with $k = 1$ should be accepted. Else, we increment $k = 2$, and repeat again. This is at worst $n$ calls to SAT decider, so it would be polynomial time, BUT the caveat is that you have to write down the formula or'd with all settings of exactly $k$ ones, of which there are $\binom{n}{k}$. In the worst case, this could take exponential time to write down, so I don't think this works. But perhaps there's another way to do it?

Comment: If SAT is in P then P=NP and so any NP problem is in P.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, I agree, I was just wondering if there was a way to see this without appealing to the Cook-Levin theorem (i.e., without using that SAT is NP complete)

Comment: You can implement a counter and so get a many-one reduction . Details left to you.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus what do you mean by a counter? It's clear I've thought about this a bit, so if you could expand a little on that idea, I'd be grateful.

Comment: The counter will count the number of ones in the assignment. You can then assert that it’s value is $k$. You can implement either a unary counter (easier) or a binary counter (more succinct).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, sure, but we cannot enumerate all assignments (or even all assignments of at most a certain value), so how do you suggest finding if there is a $k$-ones assignment in poly time, assuming a SAT decider?

Comment: You add to the SAT instance the constraint of having exactly $k$ ones, which you can encode by implementing a counter. You will get a many-one reduction.