# Why is Min-ones SAT in NP?

Tags: complexity-theory

Min-ones SAT is apparently NP-complete. I get that it is NP-hard (because SAT is trivially reduced in polynomial time to it), but I don't actually see how minimality can be verified in polynomial time.

Thus, my question: why is Min-Ones SAT in NP?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what min-ones SAT is.

Comment: I suspect that the real definition asks for the existence of a solution with *at most* a given number of ones.

Comment: Adding to Yuval Filmus' comment, I believe it is *vital* for you to provide a definition here. Min-ones SAT is usually expressed as a [*search* problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_problem), so saying it is in NP (or NP-hard, etc.) is utter nonsense. If you mean the relation from [your other post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/103398/relationship-between-sat-and-min-ones-sat), then that can hardly be framed as NP-completeness since what you refer to is a [Cook reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook_reduction), not a many-one reduction.